# Exception: Requires 'start' < 'end'

Tags: java, jfreechart

My code in main looks like this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> temper = new ArrayList<>();
     ArrayList<Float> time = new ArrayList<>();
     while(rs.next()){
         time.add(rs.getFloat("Time_ms"));
         temper.add(rs.getInt("VarValue"));                
     }
     timemax = Collections.max(time);
     timemin = Collections.min(time);         
     tempermax = Collections.max(temper);
     tempermin = Collections.min(temper);
```

I also have this class that creates a diagram:

```
public NormalDistributionDemo(final String title) {

    super(title);
    Function2D normal = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(2, 8);
    XYDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal,0, 5, 10, "Normal");
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
        "AS Hellas Database",
        "Date", 
        "Temperature", 
        dataset,
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
        true,
        true,
        false
    );
}
```

This code works fine but I want to take the values I drew from my database and insert them in the x,y axis.

I do this :

```
Function2D normal = new NormalDistributionFunction2D(tempermin, tempermax);
XYDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal,timemin, timemax,     10,"Normal");
```

And I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requires 'start' < 'end'.
at     org.jfree.data.general.DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2DToSeries(DatasetUtilities.java:542)
at     org.jfree.data.general.DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(DatasetUtilities.java:511)
at org.jfree.chart.demo.NormalDistributionDemo.<init>    (NormalDistributionDemo.java:80)
at org.jfree.chart.demo.NormalDistributionDemo.main(NormalDistributionDemo.java:71)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think the exception is quite comprehensible. It requires the value of `start` to be _smaller_ than the value of `end`. Equal values are not permitted...

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see the values of the parameters you pass to `sampleFunction2D`?

Comment: problem seems to be in XYDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal,timemin, timemax,     10,"Normal").. i think timemin is getting more then timemax

Comment: I changed the timemin to a number less than timemax and it worked just fine. Thank you all for replying!

Answer (score 1):

From [sources](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/general/DatasetUtilities.html#line.541):

```
public static XYSeries sampleFunction2DToSeries(Function2D f,
        double start, double end, int samples, Comparable seriesKey) {

    // some code

    if (start >= end) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requires 'start' < 'end'.");
    }

    // some code
}
```

It means, that `timemin` you are passing less or same as `timemax`

Answer (score 1):

My guess: you call the function

```
DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(normal,timemin, timemax, 10,"Normal");
```

The exception says

```
Requires 'start' < 'end'
```

so probably you have `timemin == timemax`. A reason can be that `ArrayList<Float> time` only has one value, or that all its values are the same.